# What do I import for SHA encryption in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, blockchain, sha

I'm trying to recreate some code from a website I found online. The code is supposed to create a blockchain in Node.js. However, when I run it, it does the recognize the command:

```
return sha(JSON.stringify(this.data) + this.prevHash + this.index + this.timestamp);
```

It returns the error:

```
return sha(JSON.stringify(this.data) + this.prevHash + this.index + this.timestamp);
                ^

ReferenceError: sha is not defined
    at Block.getHash (C:\Users\winst\OneDrive\Documents\Blockchain\main.js:12:3)
    at new Block (C:\Users\winst\OneDrive\Documents\Blockchain\main.js:8:19)
    at BlockChain.addBlock (C:\Users\winst\OneDrive\Documents\Blockchain\main.js:22:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\winst\OneDrive\Documents\Blockchain\main.js:42:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
```

What should I import in order to sha to be defined?
The whole code:

```
class Block{

    constructor(index, data, prevHash){
    this.index = index;
    this.timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    this.data = data;
    this.prevHash = prevHash;
    this.hash = this.getHash();
    }

    getHash(){
        return sha(JSON.stringify(this.data) + this.prevHash + this.index + this.timestamp);
    }
}
class BlockChain{
    constructor(){
        this.chain = [];
    }
    addBlock(data){
    let index = this.chain.length;
    let prevHash = this.chain.length !== 0 ? this.chain[this.chain.length - 1].hash : 0;
    let block = new Block(index, data, prevHash);

    this.chain.push(block);
    }
    chainIsValid(){

    for(var i=0;i<this.chain.length;i++){

        if(this.chain[i].hash !== this.chain[i].getHash()) 
            return false;

        if(i > 0 && this.chain[i].prevHash !== this.chain[i-1].hash)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}   
}
const CILCoin = new BlockChain();

CILCoin.addBlock({sender: "Bruce wayne", reciver: "Tony stark", amount: 100});
CILCoin.addBlock({sender: "Harrison wells", reciver: "Han solo", amount: 50});
CILCoin.addBlock({sender: "Tony stark", reciver: "Ned stark", amount: 75});

console.log(JSON.stringify(CILCoin, null, 4));
```

Link to website I found this from: https://codingislove.com/simple-blockchain-javascript/

Comment: There is this super cool thing called Google which I used to find the [`Hash` class](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hash) in `crypto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I like to use the [sha256 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha256).</strike> Never mind, this has been deprecated. I would instead opt for use of the [sha.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha.js) package.

```
var sha = require('sha.js');
//...
getHash() {
    return sha('sha256').update(JSON.stringify(this.data) + this.preHash + this.index + this.timestamp).digest('hex');
}
```

Comment: Recommending external packages when there is a built-in method to achieve the exact same thing is bad practice IMO.

Answer (score -2):

You might need to create your own method here, as sha() is not a function built into node. You'll need to access the `crypto` module that's part of node.

https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto

You can build a function

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const secret = 'abcdefg';
const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret)
                   .update('I love cupcakes')
                   .digest('hex');
console.log(hash);
// Prints:
//   c0fa1bc00531bd78ef38c628449c5102aeabd49b5dc3a2a516ea6ea959d6658e
```

Comment: The SHA referred to in the OP's code is not an HMAC.